# How to put button value to database Django

Tags: html, django, database, orm

do you have some tips how to put buttons values to the Django sqlite database?
I have a page with some buttons with theirs values and some final button, which would send the buttons values to the database after the final button click.

Thanks.

**Here is HTML intention:**

```
<body>
<div class="row">
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg overflow-hidden" value="1">Example1</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg overflow-hidden" value="2">Example2</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg overflow-hidden" value="3">Example3</button>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Send to database">
</form>
</body>

class ValuesButtons(models.Model):
   value = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Value")
```

**For Example:** user clicks on example 1, next on Submit and it will send to database as value 1

Comment: Can you provide some code how you're trying

Comment: your are asking for radio buttons?

Comment: @MJK618 it's in code, I have edited it. Thank you

Comment: You may wrap your form fields in form tags with some action target and method type GET/POST

Comment: @MJK618 Do you mean like me in edited code? <form></form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to submit the values in your buttons to your django database, you would have to first change your buttons by adding a name to them like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg overflow-hidden" value="1" name="btn-1">Example1</button>
```

then inside your view, you could check to see if the button was pressed and there is a value in POST. Also, this won't work if your value is "0":

```
if (request.method == "POST):
   if (request.POST.get('btn-1', False)):
       new_value_button = ValueButtons(value=request.POST.get(
'btn-1'))
       new_value_button.save()
```

This will get and save the values of the specific button pressed.